# How to craft specific packets on the host of Mininet to generate massive Packet-In messages

Tags: openflow, mininet

I am wondering that how to generate massive packet-in messages to the controller to test the response time of SDN controller in the environment of Mininet.

Can you give me some advice on it?

Comment: have you ever tried my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use iperf to send packets, like this:

```
$ iperf -c -F
```

You could specify the amount of time:

```
$IPERF_TIME (-t, --time)
```

The time in seconds to transmit for. Iperf normally works by repeatedly sending an array of len bytes for time seconds. Default is 10 seconds. See also the -l and -n options.

Here is a nice reference for iperf: https://iperf.fr/.

If you would like to use Scapy, try this:

```
from scapy.all import IP, TCP, send

data = "University of Network blah blah"
a = IP(dst="129.132.2.21")/TCP()/data
send(a)
```